# Edit Access table with autoincrease field

Tags: c#, ms-access

I use the automatically generated *`Dataset, dataadapter, bindingsource and datagridview`* to edit a `ACCESS` table with a `autoincrease` field as `ID`.

When I add a row, the `ID field` is automatically set `-1`. When I click the `ID field` cell, it automatically decrease by `1`. I do not know how to deal with it. I can not save the added row because it displays a error `"invalid parameter"`. I can not upload the image.

Comment: Are you inserting data into an autonumber field or even displaying it for editing? Do not. Autonumber fields are there to provide a unique index, they are not there for users.

Comment: The question is that how can I edit the table with Autonumber field.

Comment: You should be able to edit the record like any other. Unless you're trying to change an `Autonumber` value. That will fail/error out.

Comment: The table with autonumber does not behave like others. The autonumber field is set automatically by datagridview, dataadapter or other components without any code.

Comment: I wonder if you have ever used the automatically generated DataGridView binding with a MS-ACCESS table. The ID field is automatically set -1. I have no rights to upload a picture so I am not sure if I have make it clear.